# Retrieving routedescription geometry as GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, line, route

I'm building a small web-map and would wich to display a polyline representing a specific route via roads. With leafletjs it is easy to display the geometry on/over the map. So that's not the problem.

I'm looking for a webservice where I can 'download' the route as a polyline/Multipoint.

Does anyone know if this exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOURS navigation sites can deliver routes as geojson. Read http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS or try online

http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&flat=52.215676&flon=5.963946&tlat=52.2573&tlon=6.1799&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik

However, more often routes are available as GPX or KML format. There is a comparison matrix of OSM based services at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers but the matrix does not have a column for geojson so you must do your own research.